# failed to open hard drive

Tags: partitioning

[error message](http://s24.postimg.org/kan0eiwet/Screenshot_2015_01_03_17_34_10.png)

I've only started using linux lite yesterday, I was hyped when I was trying it booted on usb drive that I've rushed the normal instalation of it and didn't do the partition part properly (at least I think). 
I've set this drive/partition (sorry I'm confused a little) to type 'ext4' as well as some kind of location(again I'm a little confused) in the instalation.

Comment: I'm confused by the picture. Your in Linux, you have a filesystem and 3 mounted (or able to be mounted) partitions. What is this not working one? Is this another drive? Is it internal or USB? Is it empty or does it have files on it?

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention, completely dumb from my part. this is another internal hard drive and it has files in it, I was using it on windows and it did not have windows files, if it makes any difference. :) the partitions that are mounted are on a hard drive which I only use for OS purposes, since it has very small capacity. this one that I have problems with is crucial for me.

Comment: okay. We are getting closer. Was it Fat32 or NTFS partition? If you don't know, if it was XP Pro, Vista, Win7 or Win8 it would be NTFS.

Comment: I've set it to 'ext4' while installing, previously it was NTFS if I remember correctly.
edit: I might have formatted it, so I'm not sure if it has files on it.

Comment: EDIT| I can confirm that I can access the drive,since /usr location has 185gb free space. for some reason I get the error message only when I try to access it through 'drives'.|

I was running win7 previously, [this is what GParted says about the drive](http://s13.postimg.org/3tvcw6bfb/Screenshot_2015_01_03_19_50_36.png) maybe you'll spot something there. it says that its mount point is /usr and I'm able to access this location, does this mean that this drive is actually working? if so, why am I unable to access it through 'drives'?

Comment: It looks like the filesystem is still intact. See my answer, but the short answer is the reason this is not working is it is set to be ext4 and not ntfs. Also, my answer will allow you to select  a different mount point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on what you have said so far it is not clear what format the drive is in right now, or if there are any files on it. Let's assume that there are, but this should give you the info you need as well as the option to fix the setting to make it auto mount.

From Dash search for Disk and open the program called *disks*. The left side of the screen shows the disk's available and the right side of the screen shows the partition's as well as gives you details about them.

From within the *disks* program click on your Samsung drive. The left side of the screen will show you partition info. The below picture is my current partition setup on a Windows 8.1 machine, with a Recovery partition, and dual booted with Ubuntu.

[image: disks]

So when you do this and find the partition in question click on it to select it. Once selected, click on the gear looking icons and select

> Edit Mount Options

[image: Mount Options]

I suspect for you, the last option of Filesystem type will be set to 'ext4' and not 'auto'. To change it click off Automatic Mount Options

Go down to

> Filesystem Type

and type in auto.

Turn Automatic Mount Options back on and restart the computer. It should mount, and hopefully you will still have files.

Edit: You said in your comments that the mount point lists as /usr. You probably want to change that to /mnt/somedirectory. Take a look at

> Edit Mount Options

again and set the "Mount Point" setting to be something other than /usr. I suggest a subdirectory of /mnt. So for example:

```
 /mnt/Samsung
```

Don't forget to create the directory in /mnt

```
 sudo mkdir /mnt/Samsung
```